# Entity Framework Core 7 - configuring two keys

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, primary-key, .net-7.0, fluent

I have the following entities:

```
public class Account : Entity
{
    // ...
    public long RoleID { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role : Entity
{
    // ...
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string? UUID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Initially, I am trying to perform an update on an entity based on the `UUID` column instead of the `ID`, but I do not want to have to fetch the entity and then perform the update. I know that EF Core needs the primary key to track and update the entity, but is there a way to configure it to use another property?

In a second attempt, I tried to make the `UUID` become the primary key and configured the `ID` column as a secondary key using `HasAlternateKey` because I want the `ID` column to still be used for relationships between entities.

I configured it as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>
(
    e => e.HasOne(a => a.Role)
          .WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey(a => a.RoleID)
);
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>
(
    e => e.HasKey(a => a.UUID)
);
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>
(
    e => e.HasAlternateKey(r => r.ID)       
);
```

The goal was to maintain the relationship being made by the `ID` column, but the following error ends up being thrown:

> The relationship from 'Account.Role' to 'Role' with foreign key properties {'RoleID' : long} cannot target the primary key {'UUID' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Comment: In addition to `HasForeignKey` there is `HasPrincipalKey` for specifying the other side key property.

Comment: EF won't like a nullable primary key. It will assume it's not nullable in the database and throw when it encounters a record with a null value. That's worse than it looks because when you'll try to filter on `!= null` EF will ignore the filter because its thinks it's redundant. So you'll *always* have to get these records based on specified `UUID` values.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, that last setting was missing, it worked.