# Entity Framework Core 7 - Saving entities with child entities that already exists using a different key

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core 7. My entities have both an **ID** and a **UUID** and I've configured the entities with the **UUID** being the primary key and the **ID** as the foreign key.

I'm trying to find a way to save an entity with an existing child entity in the database using its **UUID** for the relationship.

For example, I have the Order and Product entity as follows:

```
public class Order
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string? UUID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string? UUID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I already have the following product saved in the database:

```
{
    UUID: "XYZ",
    ID: 1,
    Name: "Prod-1"
}
```

From my front end I'd like to be able to send the following object to save a new order by linking it to the existing product via its **UUID**.

```
{
    Name: "Order-1",
    Product: {
    UUID: "XYZ"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make EF understand this? I know my biggest problem is that I'm using the ID as the foreign key and not the UUID itself, but I'd like to know if there's any way around it.

Comment: Is the essentially different than [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78163472/861716)? (Where, BTW, I commented that you should not have nullable primary keys.)